# Liferay Message bus

Tags: liferay, messaging

I want to  create a custom message listener which also sends back response, I'm implementing MessageListener , but it has only void type method 
**public void receive(Message arg0) throws MessageListenerException**
I was trying to do 
arg0.setResponse("Test");

but it resulted in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

MessageListener is purposeds only for listening of messages without responsing. For response you can use again `MessageProducer`.